# How to get the right row in a @IBsegueAction function?

Tags: uikit, swiftui

I can segue from an embedded `UIKit tableview` to a `SwiftUI` view, with the necessary data. I select the `indexPath.row` with a `tableView(_didSelectRowAt)`. 
However, the `@IBSegueAction` takes place before the `didSelectRowAt`. This makes the detailView lag one selected row: it shows the previously selected row.

I tried to put the didSelectRowAt first, tried to embed them: no chance
I saw in a WWDC video that it should be possible lo select the right row, but can't figure out the right syntax from this short segment (about minute 6:00)
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231/

```
@IBSegueAction func MeasurementDetail(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    return UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: PointDetailSwiftUIView(pointDetail: measurements[selectedMeasurementRow]))
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedMeasurementRow = indexPath.row
    }
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In that WWDC session, Tanu doesn't care when UIKit calls `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`. Instead, her `@IBSegueAction` asks the table view for the selected row, by using `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Make sure you have a `tableView` outlet connected to your table view. You already have a `tableView` outlet if your view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Then use `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`:

```
@IBSegueAction func MeasurementDetail(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else { return nil }
    let detailView = PointDetailSwiftUIView(pointDetail: measurements[row])
    return UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: detailView)
}
```